# Passar parâmetro com array pelo HTTPGET em ajax para um ActionResult

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

Olá.

Tenho uma função em Ajax HttpGet que precisaria levar um array para um ActionResult. Como faço isso?

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'AtualizarTabelaDeRelatorio',
        data: {
            arrayDeInstalacao: arrayDeInstalacao,
            arrayDePendencias: arrayDePendencias,
            parametroDoNumeroDaPagina: pagina

        },
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            $("#dvResults").html(data);
            $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
        }
    });
```

Em C#:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AtualizarTabelaDeRelatorioDeQuantitativoDePendencia(int[] arrayDeInstalacao= null, int[] arrayDePendencias= null, int? parametroDoNumeroDaPagina = null, int? parametroDoTamanhoDaPagina = null)
    {}
```

mas não está funcionando! Obviamente porque é httpget. Não tem jeito mesmo?

Comment: mas os nomes no objeto `data` não batem com a assinatura do método, deveria ser `data: {
            'arrayDeInstalacao': arrayDeInstalacao, .... etc`

Comment: consertei, mas não é esse o problema, eu só tinha mudado quando criei o post, os nomes no projeto são os mesmos...

Comment: Exibe algum erro?

Comment: @RafaelaMarraschi Veja no console do browser qual URL está sendo usada na requisição, provavelmente está errada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rafaela, fiz um exemplo em ASP.NET CORE.

No seu código a URL não corresponde ao Controller informado. 
Um ponto importante é definir corretamente os arrays no JavaScript e informar o seguinte parâmetro no jQuery: **traditional = true**. De acordo com a documentação do jQuery, se definido como true, ele habilita o encoding padrão. Alguns frameworks "não entendem o encoding padrão".

Exemplo:

**traditional = false (Comportamento padrão)**

a%5Bone%5D=1&a%5Btwo%5D=2&a%5Bthree%5D=3&b%5B%5D=1&b%5B%5D=2&b%5B%5D=3

**traditional = true**

a[one]=1&a[two]=2&a[three]=3&b[]=1&b[]=2&b[]=3

Código abaixo...

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AtualizarTabelaDeRelatorioDeQuantitativoDePendencia(int[] arrayDeInstalacao = null, 
                                                                            int[] arrayDePendencias = null, 
                                                                            int? parametroDoNumeroDaPagina = null, 
                                                                            int? parametroDoTamanhoDaPagina = null)
    {
        return Json(arrayDeInstalacao);
    }

<div class="row">

<button id="btnEnviar" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button>
```

```
@section Scripts{ 
<script>
    $('#btnEnviar').on('click', function () {

        var arrayDeInstalacaoForm = [100, 200, 300];
        var arrayDePendenciasForm = [1, 2, 3];
        var parametroDoNumeroDaPaginaForm = 90; 
        var parametroDoTamanhoDaPaginaForm = 50;

        var request = $.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("AtualizarTabelaDeRelatorioDeQuantitativoDePendencia", "Home")', // Parâmetros - Action e Controller
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            cache: false, 
            traditional: true, 
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                arrayDeInstalacao: arrayDeInstalacaoForm,
                arrayDePendencias: arrayDePendenciasForm,
                parametroDoNumeroDaPagina: parametroDoNumeroDaPaginaForm,
                parametroDoTamanhoDaPagina: parametroDoTamanhoDaPaginaForm
            }
        }); 

        //Se a requisição for feita com sucesso...
        request.done(function (msg) {
            alert(msg)
        });

        //Se houver falha na requisição
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert(textStatus)
        });
    })
</script>
```

}

Comment: mto obrigada pela ajuda! Nesse caso ele retorna um json, né? Pois eu precisaria de um actionresult msm

Comment: É só colocar um return View()